# get navigation controller being presented in tab bar controller

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller

I used to have a design setup where when my users received a push notification, they would click on it and I would find the last navigation controller that was being presented and push some content.

I recently put all of my navigation controllers inside of a tab bar and don't know how to find the navigation controllers inside of the tab bar so that I can push to it... this is what I had before..

```
    if var window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController {

         while window.presentedViewController != nil {
             if let current =  window.presentedViewController as? UINavigationController{  
                    window = current 
                   }
             }
    }

if let window = window as? UINavigationController {
         window.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
     }
```

How do I get this to work if now my window ends up being a tab bar controller instead of the last navigation controller being presented as before?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Got it.....

```
if let tabBar = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController, var window = tabBar.selectedViewController as? UINavigationController {

         while window.presentedViewController != nil {
             if let current =  window.presentedViewController as? UINavigationController{  
                    window = current 
                   }
             }
    }

       window.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Works just like before... thanks

Comment: Thanks, this solved exactly the problem I was having.